# using form to post one variable, how to add more variables to URL without using the form?

Tags: php, forms, variables, url, get

I have a form that submits the variable id

```
search.php?id=1
```

I have 2 defined variables that need to be added to this URL

```
search.php?id=1&definedvar=$definedvar&definedvar2=$definedvar2
```

I have tried adding **a href** to the button as a **type** button, this will only submit the defined variables

If the button is type submit it will only submit the id variable

how do I combine both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form method="GET" action="search.php">
<input name="id" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="definedvar" value="<?php echo $definedvar; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="definedvar2" value="<?php echo $definedvar2; ?>" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: you should be hidding those `<input>`. It is not good to show them.

Comment: o yes, input 'definedvar" and "definedvar2" should be type="hidden" too.

Comment: So could you please add it to your answer, so that it will be fully correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can add any number of hidden inputs

```
<input type="hidden" name="definedvar1" value="<?php echo $definedvar1;?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="definedvar2" value="<?php echo $definedvar2;?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="definedvar3" value="<?php echo $definedvar3;?>"/>
```

If your form is POST you can also pass any number of GET parameters in action

```
<form action="search.php?definedvar=<?php echo $definedvar1;?>&definedvar2=<?php echo $definedvar2;?>">
```